# Angular 7: performances issues and to many call ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, angular7

I kind of new in the Angular world (I'm been working with React and Vue). Now, I'm working on a webapp with Angular 7 and I'm having several performances issues.

The main problem is that some events like clicks and mouseovers are tooking up to 4secs. I was debugging the app and realize that the event ngAfterViewChecked, it's called to many times on every click or mouse event.

[image]

I'm not 100% sure, but if the `ngAfterViewChecked` hook it's called on the `app.component.ts`, it will cause render the entire app?

And obviously, the **ngAfterViewChecked** it's called on every child component.

the app.component.ts template has only the router view.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So my question is, it's normal this amounts of calls to `ngAfterViewChecked`, or this is the reason of the slow performance? Any clue to find the main problem? Could be related with subscribers, services, shared components?

Thanks! I'm getting crazy o.O

EDIT: This is an screenshot of the Chrome performance profiler, that's indicate a several issue with few timers, is that right?

I just record an action when a click one item, it execute a ajax call, and render a list with ngFor with around 10 items.

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough context. That is perfectly normal under some circumstances but could indicate a problem under others. Use a profiling tool to determine what is bogging your app down.

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: thanks! I don't know what part of the code share because couldn't find where is located the problem yet :/ @AluanHaddad how can I do that? Chome performance tab, augury? What do you recommend?

Comment: @mauriblint I'd suggest the Chrome performance tab.

Comment: As @AluanHaddad said you really need to share code on atleast the service from where you making your ajax calls and the component subscribing on those calls. Are you using the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) at all or using other API's?